# Using Facade Like a wrapper

Tags: java, design-patterns, wrapper, anti-patterns, facade

I usually see some people used facade like this.

```
public class FooFacade {
   Foo foo;

   public boolean isFunny(param1, param2) {
       IsFunnyInput isFunnyInput = new IsFunnyInput(param1, param2);
       return foo.isFunny(isFunnyInput);
   }
}
```

Is this a right approach? In my opinion, it is just adding one more class to the package. When you can also directly use **Foo** to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it is an example of [the decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and it makes sense only if `Foo` and `FooFacade` share the same interface.

```
interface Foo { boolean isFunny(p1, p2); }
class FooFacade implements Foo { ... } // FooDecorator, actually
```

In contrast, [the Facade pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) is used to perform more complex interactions where a few different classes involved (and to hide this complexity).

[The Wrapper pattern (aka Adapter)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) implies several interfaces.

Comment: Disagree. The decorator maintains the interface while adding functionality. OP's example simplified the interface. Facade sounds correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would normally use a *Facade* to hide the inner implementation details and classes used by for example another third-party library or some complex subsystem. If the `IsFunnyInput`-Class is from another library or one submodule the facade would help you to easily switch the library or change some implementation details as it is wrapped by a facade and all your code would use the facade. 
If you're just going to wrap your self written classes that simple into a facade without additional classes involved, i do not see any real benefit!

[Here is a really good explanation of the *Facade Design pattern*](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-uncovered-1)